# Emacs. Org-mode .Archive only DONE headlines

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Windows 7, Emacs 25.1

I has **myfile.org**

It has many headlines in different state: **TODO, POSTPONED, IN PROGRESS, DONE**.
E.g.:

```
* Headline1
** IN PROGRESS Task#1_1
** DONE Task#1_2
** TODO Task1_3

* Headline2
** DONE Task#2_1
** POSTPONED Task#2_2
** TODO Task#2_3
```

I want to archive headlines only in **DONE** state. 
The result in archive file (**to.do.org_archive**) must be somethink like this:

**to.do.org_archive**

```
* Headline1
** DONE Task#1_2

* Headline2
** DONE Task#2_1
```

Is this a possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is an agenda file, I would do an agenda match search for DONE items (`C-a m TODO="DONE" RET`), mark all the items from that file with "m", and then batch archive them (e.g. `B A`).

If the file is not an agenda file, then I would add it to the agenda list with `C-c [` and then do the above. I would then take the file off the agenda list with `C-c ]`